# How to get Grails Gorm autocomplete in regular Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, grails, spring-data-jpa, grails-orm

Grails GORM is able to autogenerate ORM `findBy[fieldName]` and related methods for each of the fields in the entity, I'm not sure what magic it uses to do this I just know that IntelliJ is able to autocomplete all of these methods for free. Is there a way to get a similar behavior in Spring?

Comment: Are you asking how to get autocompletion to work in IntelliJ with Spring?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no, but how to get the same gorm behavior using spring data jpa. The behavior being gorm generating a "findBy" method for each of the entity fields without me having to do anything.

Comment: there is a tutorial on it, from grails.org , look here  [gorm without grails](https://guides.grails.org/gorm-without-grails/guide/index.html)